# UTF-8 decoding error, haskell

Tags: macos, haskell, utf-8, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile my first haskell program. Have created a simple text file as input for my .hs. But get an error: lexical error (UTF-8 decoding error).
I have seen there is a workaround for windows - `set LANG=C`. I'm on mac and next exports doesn't work for me:

```
export LANG=C
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Please copy&paste the code you are trying to compile *and* the **full** error message you get.

Comment: Probably your program is not really in UTF-8 encoding. Check the settings in your editor.

Comment: ^^ your program *file* that is, as saved by your editor. try saving it as ASCII, or UTF-8 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saved my program in UTF-8. Thanks Reid, Will